# How to package .bib files?

Tags: bibtex, miktex, texlive, package-writing

I have written some biblatex styles and provide them in the biblatex-archaeology package. I would like to have some .bib files with `@STRING` replacements for journals and serieses and example entries in the BIBINPUTS pathes. But although I indicate in [my .ins file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-archaeology/biblatex-archaeology.ins) that the databases should go to `bibtex/bib/biblatex-archaeology`, TeX Live puts them in the doc folder while MiKTeX omits them completely. What am I doing wrong? Is a TDS-packaged .zip file the only way to achieve this?

Comment: Probably you need to talk to the maintainers of the two systems: they don't simply take everything 'automatically'. In general, other than a few reference `.bib` files, these are not added to the 'live' tree as they are usually for documentation demos or similar.

Comment: An aside: I'm not sure using strings is encouraged as it ties the `.bib` to using a particular style, whereas ideally `.bib` files should be self-contained complete records.